# pointer matrix get dereferenced in the middle of the code

Tags: c, pointers

Banging my head for 1 hour, can't find the answer:

```
    int *get_possible_moves(int **board, int *w, int *h, int *x, int *y) {
 int movespossible=0;
 int moveslist[2][8];
 //4
 if(x + 1 <= w-1 && y + 2 <= h - 1) {
  if(board[*(int *)y + 2][*(int *)x + 1] == 0) {
   moveslist[movespossible][0] = *(int *)x + 1;
 breakpoint->    moveslist[movespossible][1] = *(int *)y + 2;
   movespossible++;
  }
 }
```

At a line marked breakpoint-> my **board gets dereferenced. Any clues why it is so? There are no concurrent threads that are using this place in memory. Also, I am not using **board at all at this line.

```
    //3
 if(x + 2 <= w - 1 && y + 1 <= h - 1) {
  if(board[*(int *)y + 1][*(int *)x + 2] == 0) {
   moveslist[movespossible][0] = *(int *)x + 2;
   moveslist[movespossible][1] = *(int *)y + 1;
   movespossible++;
  }
 }
```

This code works flawlessly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why all the unnecessary (int *) casts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
int moveslist[2][8];
```

... yet you often reference it:

```
moveslist[movespossible][0]
moveslist[movespossible][1]
```

... shouldn't you do it:

```
moveslist[0][movespossible]
moveslist[1][movespossible]
```

?

Comment: @Martin, yes -- a simple assert would immidately find it :)

Answer (score 0):

OKay, got it. Array out of bounds.

It quickly happens when `movespossible++` is done twice.

When array gets out of bounds, it goes on to travel in random memory space, eventually hitting board.